# Airflow: pass execution_date as param to DataflowPythonOperator

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, scheduler

I'd like to use execution date from Airflow as a parameter of my Dataflow job through using *DataflowPythonOperator*. Specifically, this job read data from Google BigQuery so that I need to provide the execution_date as a part of the query.

I tried op_kwarg and provide_context but it is seemed only applied to PythonOperator.

It's kind of look like this. In the DAG:

```
run_dataflow = DataFlowPythonOperator(
        task_id='run_dataflow',
        py_file="/path/to/main.py",
        options=dataflowoptions,
        params = execution_date
```

In main.py:

```
query = ('select * from `project_id.dataset.table`'
             'where date = {}')
query = query.format(params)
```

Comment: Not too familiar about Airflow, but where do you configure your Dataflow pipeline in this case ?

Comment: Hi @chamikara, Dataflow pipeline options are defined by `dataflowoptions` dict.

Comment: Did you try by including the execution_date in your custom PipelineOptions as per [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#creating-custom-options)?.

Comment: @Sergi Muñoz Doesn't that just create a slot for the execution_date - how do we state the value to pass to that slot?